# Comparison between non positive symmetric matrices and Frobenius Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, symmetric-matrices

Given two symmetric matrices in $\mathbb R^{N\times N}$, it is a fact that if $A\geq B \geq 0$, then $\| A\|_F \geq \| B\|_F$.

The inequalities are understood in the sense of quadratic forms, that is,
$$
A\xi \cdot \xi \geq B\xi \cdot \xi \geq 0 \quad \forall\xi\in \mathbb R^N,
$$
and $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm for matrices (which is the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^{N\times N}$).

Now, what if $A\geq B$ and $A\geq -B$, with $A$ a symmetric non negative matrix and $B$ a general symmetric matrix. Is it also true that $\| A\|_F \geq \| B\|_F$?

Comment: Sorry it is trivial : WLOG we  diagonalize B, since $\| A\|_F= | U^TAU \|_F$, with $U$ orth.. Let $d$ be the number of non negative eigenvalues, assumed to correspond to $e_1,\ldots,e_d$. In other words, $$B=\textrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d,-\lambda_{d+1},\ldots,-\lambda_{N})\textrm{ with }\lambda_i=|b_{ii}|.$$ 
Then from $A\geq B$ we get  $a_{ii} \geq \lambda_i$ for $i\leq d$ and from $A\geq -B$ we obtain $a_{ii}\geq \lambda_i$ for $i>d$. So altogether $$\sum_{i,j=1}^d a_{ij}^2\geq \sum_{i=1}^d a_{ii}^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^d b_{ii}^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^d b_{ij}^2.$$

Comment: Hi, can you give some details on how the fact in the first statement can be proven?

Comment: @Guangyao the invariance by multiplication by an orthogonal matrix is because $$\|A\|_F = \sqrt{\textrm{trace}(A^2)}.$$ And $$\textrm{trace}(A^2)=\textrm{trace}(UU^TA^2)=\textrm{trace}(U^TA^2U)=\textrm{trace}((U^TAU)^2).$$

Comment: @Guangyao In other words, let $C=U^TAU$. We have $B  Ue_i=\lambda_i Ue_i$, so $$Ce_i\cdot e_i = AUe_i\cdot Ue_i\geq B U e_i\cdot U e_i =\lambda_i.$$ Was that the question?

Comment: Or are you asking about "it is a fact that..."? in that case, the proof in the more general case given works also.